# How to set the SQL Mode on a MySQL connection in JetBrains DataGrip

Tags: mysql, datagrip, sql-mode

Does JetBrains DataGrip have any way to allow me to set the SQL_MODE automatically for my connection to a MySQL database?

For example, MySQL Workbench has a specific field for the connection that would set the SQL_MODE.  Whilst HeidiSQL provide a way to execute a Startup Script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In DataGrip, follow these steps.

1. Go to **File > Data Sources** and select your connection from the list of Project Data Source.
2. Go to the **Advanced** tab which lists *a lot* of variables.
3. Locate the the variable named **sessionVariables**. (*Tip: You can search for a particular variable by selecting any variable name, then start typing to seek.*)
4. Set the value for the variable with your SQL mode.  For example:

   ```
   sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'
   ```